# How to Remove One of Two Nodes that are Located So Close

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a Graph (read from a shapefile).
Consists of 48064 nodes, and 28837 edges.
When I draw the Graph, they look messy.

So I only took 60 first nodes to see more clearly.

Here is the Python Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

totnod = 60
shp_path = "road_exposure.shp"
net = nx.DiGraph()
G = nx.read_shp(shp_path)

# Get Some Nodes
poskey = []
posval = []
pos = {}
posx = {}
i = 0
for k,v in enumerate(G.nodes()):
    poskey.append(k)
    posval.append(v)
    posx = {k: v}
    pos.update(posx)
    i += 1
    if i == totnod:
        break

# Get Some Edges
edgsrc = []
edgdst = []
nodeedg = []
i = 0
for x in G.edges():
    nodeedg.append(i)
    edgsrc.append(x[0])
    edgdst.append(x[1])
    i += 1
    if i == totnod:
        break

# Empty graph
X=nx.Graph()

newedg = []
tplkv  = ()

for pk in poskey:
    indpkey1 = poskey.index(pk)
    src = posval[indpkey1]
    if src in edgsrc:
        indsrc = edgsrc.index(src)
        dst = edgdst[indsrc]
        inddst = edgdst.index(dst)
        pv = nodeedg[inddst]
        tplkv = (pk, pv)
        newedg.append(tplkv)

print(poskey)
print(newedg)
X.add_nodes_from(poskey)
X.add_edges_from(newedg)
nx.draw_networkx(X, pos)
plt.title('From shapefiles to NetworkX')
plt.show()
```

And here the result.

NODES:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]

EDGES:
[(0, 0), (2, 1), (4, 2), (6, 3), (8, 5), (9, 6), (10, 7), (11, 9), (12, 10), (13, 11), (14, 12), (15, 13), (16, 14), (18, 15), (20, 16), (22, 17), (24, 18), (25, 20), (26, 21), (27, 19), (28, 23), (30, 24), (32, 25), (33, 27), (34, 28), (36, 29), (38, 30), (40, 31), (42, 32), (43, 33), (44, 34), (45, 36), (46, 37), (48, 38), (50, 39), (52, 40), (54, 41), (56, 42), (57, 43), (58, 44), (59, 45)]

[The Graph drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvbei.png)

So you can see, that above graph contains many overlapping nodes, many nodes located very close, and they seemed to pile in one location.

My question:
Is there a way or an algorithm and also a function in python that I can use to remove redundant nodes / unnecessary nodes / duplicate nodes (the nodes that located very near/close), so I will have a clearer graph.

Answer (score 0):

You talk about nodes being "close".  Since your nodes have no attributes apart from their index number, it is not immediatly clear what "close" means.

Best guess: close nodes have one or few hops on the shortest path between them.  If this is what you mean, then I would suggest:

```
for every node
  find number ( Hn ) of other nodes that are less then H hops away
Sort nodes in order of their Hn
Nm = 0
loop Ns over nodes in order of decreasing Hn
  loop Nd over nodes that have been displayed
     if path from Ns to Nd has less then H hops
        break out of Nd loop ( Ns is already "represented" by Nd )
  Display Ns
  Nm++
  if Nm > M
     stop
```

Experiment with the values of H and M until you find a pleasing result.

Second Guess: you mean nodes that end up close in the display.  This depends on the layout program you are using to create the display.  In this case, there are two approaches:

A adjust the parameters of the layout program

B Read the locations of the nodes after the layout program has processed them.  Use a clustering algorithm (K-Means should work fine ) to select representative nodes and display only those, using the original locations from the layout of the entire graph.

Answer (score 0):

Graph visualization is a very hard problem, and the `networkx` library
has some selected functions to draw graphs. However, using shell drawing, the
result looks already a lot better than what you started with.

The algorithm below takes your selected 60 nodes and their edges and
groups the nodes based on degree, drawing the inner shell of nodes with
degree 0 (not so much space needed), followed by shell with degree 1
nodes and then degree 2.

More is possible by small manipulations of the data; observe that 58 is
"blocking" an edge from 36 to 29. Why not swap the positions of these nodes?
Also, 45 has an edge to 36, so put those nodes together.

```
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

NODES = range(60)
EDGES = [(0, 0), (2, 1), (4, 2), (6, 3), (8, 5), (9, 6),
         (10, 7), (11, 9), (12, 10), (13, 11), (14, 12),
         (15, 13), (16, 14), (18, 15), (20, 16), (22, 17),
         (24, 18), (25, 20), (26, 21), (27, 19), (28, 23),
         (30, 24), (32, 25), (33, 27), (34, 28), (36, 29),
         (38, 30), (40, 31), (42, 32), (43, 33), (44, 34),
         (45, 36), (46, 37), (48, 38), (50, 39), (52, 40),
         (54, 41), (56, 42), (57, 43), (58, 44), (59, 45)]
net = nx.DiGraph()
net.add_nodes_from(NODES)
net.add_edges_from(EDGES)
# Group nodes based on degree to use shell graph drawing
ndegree = [(node, nx.degree(net, node)) for node in NODES]
g1 = itertools.groupby(sorted(ndegree, key=lambda x: x[1]), key=lambda x: x[1])
shells = tuple(tuple(x[0] for x in g) for _,g in g1)
# pos = nx.planar_layout(net)
pos = nx.shell_layout(net, nlist=shells)
nx.draw_networkx(net, pos)
plt.title('From shapefiles to NetworkX')
plt.show()
```